# Python/Pandas merge and generate list of unique values from comma separated variable/column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table that looks like this:
[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohxXW.png)

```
LOCATION   ANALYSIS TYPE
A          A,B,C,D
A          D,E,F
B          KA
B          A,B,C
B          C,D,E
```

I wish to generate a single line inventory for each location that lists the Analysis types available using `pandas`.  So, for this column of lists I want to merge and display a single list of unique values by location.

```
IE:
A         A,B,C,D,E,F
B         A,B,C,D,E,KA
```

[DESIRED TABLE_OUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykzg2.png)

Sorry, no code.  I have tried various splits in pandas, not getting close.

Comment: Could you post some of the splits you tried in pandas?

Comment: Played with splitting on the "," in the list.  It made a new column for each item....nowhere near what I was trying to accomplish. :D

Comment: You shouldn't have edited your question with images. Leave the tables as text.

Comment: Dang..."im helping"

Comment: Text is back...I need to sort out how to format a table in here.  This is my first post...please dont hate me :D

Comment: G. Anderson...this is close.  Only difference is in my case column B is already a list..I will give it a try.  Thanks

Comment: This works, mostly.  For some reason it keeps duplicates, each row is surrounded by single quotes.  IE actual output:00/01-03-002-20W4/0 ['TSPM, TSPT, XRD', 'TSPM, TSPT, XRD', 'TSPM, TSPT, XRD', 'TSPM, TSPT, XRD', 'TSS', 'TSS', 'TSS', 'TSS', 'CHST', 'CHST', 'CHST', 'CHST', 'CHST', 'CHST', 'CHST', 'CHST', 'CHST', 'CHST', 'CHST', 'CHST']
00/01-03-016-01W5/0 ['SEMP', 'SEMP', 'SEMS', 'SEMS']

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Location':['A']*2+['B']*3
                   ,'Analysis_Type':['A,B,C,D','D,E,F','KA','A,B,C','C,D,E']})
df1.set_index('Location')['Analysis_Type'].str.split(',')\
   .groupby(level=0)\
   .agg(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(list(set(x.sum())))))\
   .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Location Analysis_Type
0        A   A,B,C,D,E,F
1        B  A,B,C,D,E,KA
```

Comment: df_newrng.set_index('UWI')['Analysis Test Type'].str.split(',')\
   .groupby(level=0)\
   .agg(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(list(set(x.sum())))))\
   .reset_index()

Comment: I get a type error.  Sorry figuring out how to do line breaks :D

Comment: "\" is a line continuation character....

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted...using the example data.  With the real world data I am having sytax problems...but it will get there.  *Hi-5 Scott Boston*